# Add condition to search box in Google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, search

I am new in android and working for developing an app with Google maps V2. I designed map and every thing is OK. I put a textbox and button at the top that help user to search for any location he want and used this  bottom method to the search operation. The problem when the user enter invalid place the app crashed.
I want to add condition with toast in this method that when the user enter invalid location, the toast appear( please enter a valid location )

please help me

```
public void search(View v) throws IOException{

    EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String location = textboxt.getText().toString();
    if (location.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    Address add = list.get(0);
    String locality = add.getLocality();
        double lat = add.getLatitude();
    double lng = add.getLongitude();
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));
            // zoom in Google map
            Gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
```

Comment: yes the code working well (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check you `List<Address> list` with `list.size()==0` if i am not wrong then it's work. try like:

```
try{

if(list.size()!=0){
//Your code
}else{
 //Error Message
 } 

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();

}
```

**Update:** try to implement your code like a way:

```
public void search(View v){

EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String location = textboxt.getText().toString();
if (location.length() == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter a location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{

try{

Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);

List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);


if(list.size()!=0){

Address add = list.get(0);
String locality = add.getLocality();
    double lat = add.getLatitude();
double lng = add.getLongitude();
LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
Gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll));
        // zoom in Google map
        Gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
}else{
 Toast.makeText(this, "Location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } 

}catch(Exception e){
e.printstacktrace();

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will try it now and tell the result

Comment: there is error in (e.printstacktrace();

the method is undefined for type Exception

Comment: @user3350437 `e.printStackTrace();`  just S and T caiptal

Comment: @user3350437 you forget to add `}` one more at the end

Comment: thanks Eng  Manish , the code true , iam so sorry for annoying u >